# Distinguish between logging into a newly established SSO session and login using an existing SSO session

Tags: java, spring

I have a scenario whereby 2 separate applications use SSO for authentication via OAuth2.

I would like to execute some custom code ONLY when the user has logged into an application and had to provide their credentials i.e an SSO session did not already exist.

The problem with the code below is that `onAuthenticationSuccess` is invoked when:

- The user logs in to AppA by providing their creds and creating a new SSO session
- An SSO session already exists, and the user logs into AppB without having to provide their creds

Is there any way to distinguish between these 2 scenarios?

`CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java`:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
  private String homeUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Successful user authentication!");
    String redirectionUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(homeUrl)
        .build().toUriString();
    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, redirectionUrl);
  }
}
```

`SecurityConfiguration.java`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login().successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    }
}
```

I'm using the following dependancies:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.2.6.RELEASE")
implementation("org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.1.RELEASE")
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.2.0.RELEASE")
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.2.0.RELEASE")
```

Comment: Please provide your dependencies - are you using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`?

Comment: @StavShamir Updated question with dependancies from `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oauth2Login` `successHandler` is invoked only after the authentication has been made and saved, so it is too far down stream to be able to distinguish between the first time the user signed in and following sign ins.

There is a solution, however. 
The class responsible for saving the authorization is `InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService`. Sadly, it is `final`, so you can't extend it, but you can copy it and modify its `saveAuthorizedClient` client method in which you can check if this is a new user:

```java
public class CustomOAuth2AuthorizedClientService implements OAuth2AuthorizedClientService {

    ...

    @Override
    public void saveAuthorizedClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient, Authentication principal) {
        // If this is the first sign in, the authorized client will be null
        boolean isFirstSignIn = null == this.loadAuthorizedClient(authorizedClient.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(),
                authorizedClient.getPrincipalName());

        if (isFirstSignIn) {
            ...
        }

        this.authorizedClients.put(new OAuth2AuthorizedClientId(authorizedClient.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(),
                principal.getName()), authorizedClient);
    }

    ...
}
```

And provide it as a bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class AuthorizedClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClient oAuth2AuthorizedClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new CustomOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }

}
```